# DirectoryNotEmptyException exception unknowingly why

Tags: java

I have the following code that should replace an image in a folder inside Local AppData, although I get an exception saying "java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Roblox\Versions\version-76a406688204424a\content\textures". What can I do?

Code:

```
package robloxstudioclassimageloader;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RobloxStudioClassImageLoader {
    
    private static Path pathFile = Paths.get("resources/ClassImages.png");
    private static Scanner scanner;
    private static String path;
    private static Path textureFile;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            scanner = new Scanner(new File("resources/path.txt"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        path = scanner.nextLine();
        textureFile = Paths.get(path);
        File RobloxPath = new File(path);
        if(RobloxPath.isDirectory()){
            for (final File versionEntry : RobloxPath.listFiles()) { //versions folder
                if (versionEntry.isDirectory()) {
                   for (final File contentEntry : versionEntry.listFiles()) { //version folder
                        if (contentEntry.isDirectory()) {
                            if(contentEntry.getName().equals("content")){
                                for (final File contentEntry2 : contentEntry.listFiles()) { //content folder
                                    if (contentEntry2.getName().equals("textures")) {
                                        for (final File textureEntry : contentEntry2.listFiles()) { //texture file
                                            if(textureEntry.getName().equals("ClassImages.PNG") || textureEntry.getName().equals("ClassImages.png")) {
                                                System.out.println(textureEntry.getName());
                                                Path endPath = Paths.get(textureEntry.getParent());
                                                System.out.println(endPath);
                                                try{
                                                    Files.copy(pathFile,endPath,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                                                }catch(Exception e){
                                                    System.out.println(e);
                                                }
                                                System.out.println("ENDED");
                                                System.exit(0);
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about ```if (!endPath.toFile().isDirectory()) Files.copy(pathFile, endPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
``` ? If that's not quite right, it might give you a clue

Comment: That wasn't exactly what I needed but it gave me the clue! Thanks!

Comment: @CristeaOctavian so what was is?

Comment: @caduceus, ohh, I don't really remember. I finished the project 6+ plus months ago, and I don't have the slightest idea what was the issue.